# javascript function is not called in order in Internet explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, internet-explorer-9

I am calling two functions in jqgrid:

```
var AdGrid = ConstructJQgrid(gridId, GridModel, true, gridComplete);

$(AdGrid).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
```

### Testing in Chrome:

From the above javascript code, the first method `ContructJQgrid` is called and will return results by calling `controller` and the results will be stored in the variable `AdGrid`.

By using the `AdGrid`'s value, I am calling `jqGrid` method and it returns the grid.

This is the actual working scenario and works fine with **Google chrome** browser.

### Testing in Internet Explorer (Version:9.0):

In this, first it is calling the `ContructJQgrid` and without calling the `controller`it is executing the `jqgrid` method and hence my grid has not get constructed, results in error.

**NOTE:** My `controller` is calling, but not at the required time in **IE9**.

How to work this scenario in **Internet Explorer(Version:9.0)**?

Comment: What is your controller code doing?

Comment: do you execute the code after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: You should include **the code of `ConstructJQgrid`**. You should always write **which version of jqGrid you use**. Instead of that you included only two lines of code. The second line `$(AdGrid).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel")` returnes the `colModel` and the usage it without an assignment has no sense. So you should post more code and describe more clear what you do. Probably you should move some your code inside of `loadComplete` callback.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the asynchronous behavior of JavaScript. The second function gets called even when the first function has not finished with its execution. I suggest that you add that second line `$(AdGrid).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");` in the end of the definition of the function `var AdGrid = ConstructJQgrid(gridId, GridModel, true, gridComplete);` .

There is another way of doing it, use the concept of callback function 
    `

```
var AdGrid = ConstructJQgrid(gridId, GridModel, true, gridComplete,
        function () {
            $(AdGrid).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
        });
```

`

Comment: Thank you. I will try with the above solution